# different editors for different perspectives in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, perspective

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse plugin - Editor associated to file extension and perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857048/eclipse-plugin-editor-associated-to-file-extension-and-perspective)

I have two perspective that manages the same files. I would like to make an association between file extension - editor - perspective.

I mean if I open the file extension .XXX in perspective 1 it uses the editor A, but if I open the same file extension .XXX in perspective 2, it uses the editor B.

Is it possible? And please don't tell me to avoid it.

Thanks